# VB.net Hash Algorithm

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, hash, md5, sha1

I am working on a Desktop Application using VB.net with an existing database. Including the user's username and password, I want to do the login window using the existing password but it was hashed password. May I know what hash algorithm use in this data **X8NUoMVWb/w6D4QdmumxoQ==**?

Comment: @Dai while I wouldn't necessarily recommend VB for new commercial development, I don't think it merits shouty incredulity.

Comment: @Dai Why not  vb.net? It is still a member in good standing of the .net languages family and I don't have to add a semicolon at the end of every line.

Answer (score 4):

You can make an educated guess simply by looking at the length of the hash, as generally there's only a handful of *popular* hashing algorithms used for passwords, all with their own distinct output lengths:

| Hash | Output length (bytes) | Output length (bits) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MD5 | 16 | 128 |
| SHA-1 | 24 | 160 |
| SHA-2 (SHA256) | 32 | 256 |
| SHA-2 (SHA512) | 64 | 512 |

You can never know *for sure* because while different hashing algorithms have different output sizes, the output can always be truncated (or padded with random bytes).

That said, `X8NUoMVWb/w6D4QdmumxoQ==` is a Base64-encoded binary value which decodes to a 16-byte value. 16 bytes is 128 bits - it's very likely **this is an MD5 hash value**.

The 16 bytes convert to Base 16 (hexadecimal) are `5FC354A0C5566FFC3A0F841D9AE9B1A1`.

This MD5 hash doesn't appear in any freely available leaked password databases or hash-reverse services I tried.

---

Note [that systems like `bcrypt` generate an output string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) which is *not just* a hash-value, but actually a data structure containing the hash and other data. In bcrypt's case the string always starts with `$2` which will never appear in a Base16 or Base64-encoded string.

Comment: Note that it **could** be a salted hash. And the salt _might_ be stored elsewhere in the application's database or security system.